# Wordpress: Reverse engineer MySQL

Tags: wordpress, reverse-engineering, erd

Guys i reversed engineered a wordpress database to EER diagram in hope of seeing some relationships but it seems the tables arent linked?

I also reversed engineered to visio and to MySQL Workbench but i get the same result an EER diagram without relationships? if someone knows the reason for this please explain

Comment: You might want to check this [link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description) for the tables relantionship in WP database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a WAD. ("Works as designed".)

> Please note that within the standard installation of WordPress no
>   integrity between the tables is enforced e.g. between posts and
>   comments. If you are creating a plugin or extension that manipulates
>   the WordPress database, your code should do the housekeeping so that
>   no orphan records remain in the tables e.g. by removing records in
>   other tables with a set of SQL commands when foreign keys are deleted
>   (Don't forget to remind users to backup before such operations).

[Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description)

WordPress uses the MyISAM engine. MyISAM doesn't enforce foreign key constraints anyway.